# Reproject Equirectangular .cub file to Orthographic Project - using GDAL

Tags: gdal, netcdf

I’m trying to plot an image of the Moon, with a good version of the topography (or even a nice picture). I then want to overlay the Apollo landing sites. This locations should be pretty accurate - although the final image need only be less than 8 cm x 8 cm. I’d like to use python Basemap and I’m reasonably familiar with its use. I probably want the final image to be an Orthographic projection.

If anyone has simple suggestions - such as a ready made netCDF in the right projection, please let me know!

I think the LOLA topography has what I want, but I’m struggling to transform file formats and the projection.

I have downloaded the file  Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.cub   from
https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014/cub

The output of the command

> gdalinfo Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.cub  -mm is shown
>   below. This is an Equirectangular projection in meters. The
>   information is in Band 1, is Int16 and does not have a colour
>   specified.

So I need to transform it to a netCDF file (this seems to work).
I also need to reproject it to an 'ortho' projection, and I need to downsample it. I am using gdal, which is new to me. Neither command is working properly - it seems that the resampling is messing with the range of the output (it should be from  approximately -5000 to +1000, but the range is much greater after resampling, and the colour becomes specified as grayscale.

downsample:

```
gdalwarp -tr 1024 1024 -r bilinear Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.cub a1_resampled.cub
```

reproject:

```
gdalwarp a1_resampled.cub b1.cub -t_srs "+proj=ortho +a=1737400. +units=m"
```

make a netCDF file:

```
gdal_translate -of netCDF b1.cub a_trans.nc

(gdal)bash-3.2$ gdalinfo Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.cub  -mm


Driver: ISIS3/USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 3)
Files: Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014.cub
Size is 92160, 46080
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["SimpleCylindrical Moon",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Moon",
        DATUM["D_Moon",
            SPHEROID["Moon",1737400,0]],
        PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Equirectangular"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0]]
Origin = (-5458203.076608000323176,2729101.538304000161588)
Pixel Size = (118.450587600000006,-118.450587600000006)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-5458203.077, 2729101.538) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-5458203.077,-2729101.538) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 5458203.077, 2729101.538) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 5458203.077,-2729101.538) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=1024x1024 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
```